# Installing quantlib for javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, quantlib

I am trying to install quantlib for `javascript` on both linux and windows. I get a similar error in both cases.

```
[idf@node3 ql]$ sudo npm install quantlib
[sudo] password for idf: 

> quantlib@0.2.1 postinstall /home/idf/Documents/js/node_modules/quantlib
> node-pre-gyp install

node-pre-gyp ERR! install error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/quantlibnode/quantlibnode/releases/download/v0.2.1/linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/idf/Documents/js/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js:120:27)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (/home/idf/Documents/js/node_modules/request/request.js:1029:10)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:474:21)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/idf/Documents/js/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/idf/Documents/js/node_modules/quantlib
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.33
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/quantlibnode/quantlibnode/releases/download/v0.2.1/linux-x64.tar.gz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/idf/Documents/js/package.json'
npm WARN js No description
npm WARN js No repository field.
npm WARN js No README data
npm WARN js No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install" "quantlib"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! quantlib@0.2.1 postinstall: `node-pre-gyp install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the quantlib@0.2.1 postinstall script 'node-pre-gyp install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the quantlib package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs quantlib
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls quantlib
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/idf/Documents/js/ql/npm-debug.log
[idf@node3 ql]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [quantlib.js](https://quantlib.js.org/docs/) now, it's pure javascript and can be used in both node.js and browser

Answer (score 0):

Do you meet the following requirements:
[enter link description here](https://vineetv.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/installing-quantlib-python-windows/)

Comment: this has nothing to do with python. However, FWIW, on the same computer, I have quantlib python working.

Answer (score 0):

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/quantlibnode/quantlibnode/releases/download/v0.2.1/linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The Linux error points to the fact hat `npm` cannot find v0.2.1 tarball version for Linux in Github. Taking a look at the installation instructions, it looks like it cannot be installed via `npm` for linux, but has to be done from scratch manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the error message:

```
https://github.com/quantlibnode/quantlibnode/releases/download/v0.2.1/linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The file is simply not there, and thus nothing can be done. Check the URL link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creator of quantlib.node project, sorry for the late response.

Right now, only windows 32/64 bit pre-build are provided. For Mac and Linux, you'll have to build the addon yourself.

The reason Mac/Linux pre-build is missing is that, the building process is a bit complicated, on Mac/Linux we can't use pre-build quantlib, we need to build it from source and add certain flags: like `-std=c++11`, which is required by node

And I did try using static linking to boost and quantlib(to remove the library dependency), the generated addon is very big, 200M+ (after tar.gz). This is not convenient for download.

For now, please follow the [steps in README.md](https://github.com/quantlibnode/quantlibnode#building-the-native-addon) to build the addon, you probably want to build it using dynamic linking, so the generated addon is much smaller.

I'll see if I can make this part easier, please stay tuned